# Merging an array with DataProvider data items

Tags: php, yii

I have 2 tables in my Yii application; **Category** and **Item**.

```
Category
- id
- name

Item
- id
- category_id
- name
```

What I would like to do is get a list of items in **Category** table and subsequently count the number of items of each category in the **Item** table.

I'm using CActiveDataProvider to retrieve a list of items in the the Category table and then subsequently use a for-loop to count the number of items in each category. However, I can't seem to figure out how to merge the array with my DataProvider data items.

Here is my code so far.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Category', array(
        'criteria' => array(
            'select' => 'id, name, slug',
            'order' => 'name ASC',
        ),
    ));
    $dataProvider->setPagination(false);
    $count = array();
    foreach($dataProvider->getData() as $categoryData) {
        $count[] = Item::model()->count("category_id = :categoryID", array("categoryID" => $categoryData->id));
    }
    $this->render('index', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'count' => $count,
    ));
}
```

How do I merge the $count array with my existing dataProvider data items so that I may use it with CListView? Is there a much more better solution than this?

Comment: You shouldn't need to if you have your relations setup correctly. Can you show what is on the index view.

Comment: Actually if you are using the default gii created files can you share your `_view.php` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need a seperate count array if your relationships are setup correctly. Most likely your `index` view looks like this:

```
<h1>Messages</h1>
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
```

Then your `_view` should look like this:

```
<div class="view">
    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('id')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), array('view', 'id'=>$data->id)); ?>
    <br />
    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('name')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->name); ?>
    <br />
    <b>Items:</b>
    <?php echo count($data->items); ?>
    <br />
</div>
```

This is assuming your `Category` model has this:

```
public function relations() {
        return array(
            'items' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Item', 'category_id'),
        );
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the solution. My relationship has already been defined and I just applied the count($data->items) line on my view. Works perfectly.